# Conditional Form Validation w/ Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm developing a simple form using Bootstrap 4.  I would like to do some conditional form validation, based on whether a checkbox is checked or not.  Help?

EDIT:

For anyone that finds this.  Here is the solution I came up with that works well.

```
$("#checkbox-id").change(function() {
     if(this.checked) {
          $("#conditional-input-id").prop('required', true);
     } else {
          $("#conditional-input-id").prop('required', false);
     }
});
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Have you [read the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#how-it-works)?

Comment: I'm attempting a simple jquery function to add the 'required' tag to the elements that should be conditionally required.  The docs didn't really have an example on how to do this, hence the question.